# empty pointers as an argument in C - problem with asterisks

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference, function-definition

The task is to fill an array with numbers by user input and then use our stats() function to calculate average etc. of each row of this array. The header of stats() function looks as follows:

```
int stats(int (*ptr)[5], int width, int height, int row_id, int* max, int* min, float *avg)
```

where ptr is a pointer to the matrix,width and height are its size, row_id is the index of analysed row and max, min and avg are pointers to variables storing each statistics.

When calling a function with such line:

```
stats(*ptr, 5,5,2, *max = NULL, *min = NULL,  *avg=NULL);
```

the following error appears:

```
 error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
```

I tried different approaches but there is always a mistake, how can I fix that? Thank you for any clues.

edit:
Here's the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int stats(int (*ptr)[5], int width, int height, int row_id, int* max, int* min, float *avg)
{
    int j, vmax,vmin;
    int max = &vmax;
    int min = &vmin;
    int i = row_id;
    int m = *ptr;

    for(j = 0; j<5; j++){
        if(m[i][j]>max)
        {
            max = m[i][j] ;
            j++;
            else
                j++;
        }

    }
printf("%d", max);
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    int n, i, j, vmin, vmax; // vmax - value of the maximum
    int min = &vmin; // min - pointer to the minimum
    int max = &vmax;
    float vavg;
    int avg = &vavg;
    int m[5][5];

    for(i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j<5; j++)
        {
            printf("ENTER A NUMBER: ");
            scanf("%d", &n);
            m[i][j] = n;
        }
    }
    int ptr = &m;
    stats(*ptr, 5,5,2, *max = NULL, *min = NULL,  *avg=NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For starters the function declaration is senseless. For example what does the function return? Or what  is the meaning of row_id?

Comment: Obviously `*ptr` has a wrong type for the call, but you did not show how it is declared, so we cannot be sure what expression has the right type. `ptr` might work, or it might not. Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: As the post states, `row_id` is the index of the row of the matrix to operate on.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This is nothing more than a stupidity. If the function operates on one row then it should be declared for one-dimensional array without any row_id.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it may operate on any row given by the user

Comment: @wojech min declared like int min = &vmin; is not a pointer.

Comment: @wojech As I pointed to the function declaration is senseless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code full of bugs.

For example `min` and `max` are not declared as pointers

```
int min = &vmin; // min - pointer to the minimum
int max = &vmax;
```

Also it is unclear why the variable `avg` has the type `int` and is initialized by a pointer expression of the type `float *`.

```
float vavg;
int avg = &vavg;
```

Or the variable `ptr` of the type `int` is initialized by the address of the two-dimensional array.

```
int ptr = &m;
```

As for the function  then if the function operates only on one row then there is no any sense to pass to the function the whole two-dimensional array.

Also the return type and the returned value of the function do not make a sense.

And the function shall not output any message. It is the caller of the function that will decide output a message or not.

And also the function contains bugs where you are redeclaring its parameters like for example

```
int max = &vmax;
```

that again does not make a sense.

Using your approach the function can be declared and defined the following way

```
#include <assert.h>

//...

void stats( const int *a, size_t n, int *max, int *min, float *avg )
{
    assert( n != 0 );

    *max = a[0];
    *min = a[0];
    float sum = a[0];

    for( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        sum += a[i];

        if ( *max < a[i] )
        {
            *max = a[i];
        }
        else if ( a[i] < *min )
        {
            *min = a[i];
        }
    }

    *avg = sum / n;
}
```

And called like

```
int min = 0;
int max = 0;
float avg = 0.0f;;

//...

stats( m[2], 5, &max, &min, &avg );

printf( "max = %d\n", max );
printf( "min = %d\n", min );
printf( "average = %f\n", avg );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using pointers as function parameters be carefull. If you have something like this:

```
int func(int *max){

}
```

max ,here, is a pointer which needs to hold an address. So inside this function when you need use it, you need to dereference it by using `*`. For example:

```
int func(int *max){
   *max = $someAddress
}
```